# Find an example of a homomorphism of $D_4$ to $Z_8$ such that $\ker=\{e,R,F\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

The question asks to find an example of a homomorphism of $D_4$ to $Z_8$ such that $\ker=\{e,R,F\}$.

$$D_4 = \{e, R,R^2,R^3,F,FR,FR^2,FR^3\} \text{ and } Z_8=\{0,\ldots,7\}$$

I thought about letting the map equal:
$$\phi(e)=0$$
$$\phi(F)=0$$
$$\phi(R)=0$$

But I wouldn't know how to map the other elements
$\phi(R^2),\phi(R^3),\ldots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel of a homomorphism must be a subgroup so this is impossible.